# why the org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik:1.16 dependencies did not downloaded

Tags: java, gradle

Today I want to ad batik into my project, then I added the gradle(7.4) dependencies like this:

```
implementation 'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik:1.16'
```

after I refresh the gradle dependencies, I found the dependencies jar did not added to my project, why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem? I already checked the repo https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik/1.16 and found the version I added was uploaded. This is the full build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.leetcode'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    implementation('com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.76')
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik:1.16'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik:1.16` is not a regular jar artefact that you can import as a jar dependency, it's a parent pom artefact , see its content in [sonatype](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik/1.16) or here in [mavencentral](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik/1.16/batik-1.16.pom)

You'll need to import the right dependency depending on your need, for example you could import the `batlik-all` jar as follows

```
implementation 'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-all:1.16'
```